# Google sheets. How calculate sum of three max values in a row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have the values in a row:

14  5   10  1   14  18

I need to take three max values (in the case it is 14 + 14 + 18) and calcualte their sum.
Can anybody help me how write a formula?

I didn't find precise formala for that. Maybe some formala's combianation is requred here.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(A1:F1,{1,2,3}))
```

Or:

```
=INDEX(SUM(LARGE(A1:F1,{1,2,3})))
```

Comment: `SUM` would be sufficient, even for old versions of Excel!

Comment: @JosWoolley, it's meant to work for GS =)

Comment: Ah! And `SUM` doesn't in GS? Interesting...

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(LARGE(A1:F1,{1,2,3})) works perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=SUM(SORTN(FLATTEN(A1:F1),3,,1,0))
```

For Excel, try-

```
=SUM(INDEX(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:F1),1,-1),SEQUENCE(3)))
```

With most recent version, use-

```
=SUM(TAKE(SORT(TOCOL(A1:F1),1,-1),3))
```

[image]

Comment: Why isn't it just `=SUM(LARGE(A1:F1,{1,2,3}))`? Sometimes these new Excel functions lead us to forget more simple set-ups!

Comment: @JosWoolley Because, new formulas are easier and more efficient. I thought about legacy formulas.

Comment: Can you clarify re "*more efficient*"? `=SUM(INDEX(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:F1),1,-1),SEQUENCE(3)))` is calling 5 functions, whereas `=SUM(LARGE(A1:F1,{1,2,3}))` is only calling 2.

Comment: Just a FYI but `SORT()` does not need rows per se in Excel. For example `=SUM(TAKE(SORT(A1:F1,,,1),,-3))` does the trick too.

Comment: @JosWoolley I do not mean this formula but new dynamic formulas.